PostgreSQL: how to convert unicode escape sequences to readable text?
I have a database table with texts where characters with diacritics are represented using Unicode escape sequences. For example: the text which would normally read nezjištěno is represented as nezji\u0161t\u011Bno.
In PostgreSQL, I can do: SELECT E'nezji\u0161t\u011Bno'; and it will return the correct human-readable representation of the string literal. I would like to do the same thing as the "E" switch does, but when selecting data from table, is that possible to do?

I think you may find this kind os stuff is down to the encoding defined at the database level. EG for SQL Server - in SSMS You get something like this in database properties: Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

What is "not human-readable" about a Unicode string? Safe for control characters (in the low ASCII) the rest is normal text.

@TheImpaler Not readable as in I can't display it to humans.

@JGFMK I believe the DB is set up correctly, but some export process is loading data in this format into it, there's not much I can do about it.

Yes, but a Chinese ideogram is human-readable, as well as Katakana, and Greek and Cyrillic letters. What Unicode character are you having trouble displaying?

@TheImpaler not any particular character, but the string was encoded so that characters with Czech diacritics have been encoded as \uXXXX – that's what isn't human-readable.

SELECT unistr('nezji\u0161t\u011Bno');

   unistr   
════════════
 nezjištěno
(1 row)


Thanks. This seems to have trouble with some special non-alphanumeric characters in the string, but nevertheless I believe this is what I was looking for.

Which characters give you trouble?

The content of the field is a JSON, but it is stored as a TEXT type, not JSON type. Probably some of the JSON curly brackets are breaking it. I reckon I should be able to cast it to JSON and then use UNISTR on the extracted text.
